# Is there a built in .net string/double object for combo boxes?

Tags: .net, string, combobox, double, built-in

When adding items to a ComboBox I know that I could simply define some object and modify `.ToString()`

Is there a built-in object that already does this on a double/string combination?

That is:
I know that I can do this:

```
 myCombo.Items.Add(New MyItem(myString,myDouble));
```

Is there a built-in type such that I can do this:

```
myCombo.Items.Add(New SomeBuiltInType(myString,myDouble));
```

All I want is to display `myString` in the box and be able to read `myDouble` from the selected item... or some combination of `myString` and `myDouble` is also fine.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing what you'd want to *do* to the string and double combination.

Comment: Given there are two data types, how would you expect the "toString" to function? Would it always output `String.Format("{0} ({1}"), str, dbl);` for instance?

Comment: @JonSkeet Just a property bag to fill the ComboBox where `myString` is displayed in some way

Comment: @BradChristie In this case I don't particularly care. I want it to output `myString;` or `String.Format("{0} ({1})"), myString, myDouble);`

Comment: Doh! I feel dumb now... of course I can just use use a `KeyValuePair<string,double>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) since each entry is a [`KeyValuePair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx).

Comment: But the `ToString` gives both.

Comment: Use the DisplayMember property.

Comment: +1, assuming (new KeyValuePair<String,Double>("foo",13.37)).ToString()` and `[Foo, 13.37]` is acceptable as output.

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't one that you can use.